# PHP redmine-ci on http://ellislab.com/

Tags: php, codeigniter, redmine

I'm trying to run this redmine written in PHP. Because my server supports PHP only. And redmine.org is written in ruby. So I found this project: https://code.google.com/p/redmine-ci/

But it is written with http://ellislab.com framework. But I don't know this framework and it doesn't work.

I set database in application/config/database.php and 
base url in application/config/config.php but nothing happeng.

Firs I get ERROR 404 so I have tried change .htaacess but it still doesn't work. There is SVN and whole code + sql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try and provide more information if you are really interested in getting help on this topic.

The 404 means a file you requested was not found. The 404 can be generated either by the web server, or the codeigniter framework. I can't tell you which one because you need to at least say what your url is.

If the 404 error is generated by apache, then it probably means the index.php is not accessible, as codeigniter uses this script as a bootstrap script for all requests.

If the error is generated by codeigniter itself, then it means codeigniter cannot find a controller, or controller method you are accessing. This would be specified in your url, for example http://myredmine.site/somecontroller/somemethod/

If your URL is not specifying a controller and.or method, then look at the default route in the applications/config/routes.php file.

Comment: Thank you, no I got redmine.site/project and I checked /application/controllers/project.php and this file is empty :( So I think this projct haven't been finished. So thank you.